# Spring security *always* redirects to login form

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, nginx, spring-security, jetty

I'm having a webapp with *spring-security 3.1.0* enabled which works just fine locally using.

```
mvn jetty:run
```

When deployed remotely on jetty (behind nginx on port 80) spring-security stops working all together. That is, the rest of the webapp works except for the parts that are secured.

---

### The problem

When I navigate to a secured location I get redirected to the login page so that part works. The problem is that when submitting the login form nothing seems to happen. I always come back to the login form like nothing has happened.

When I try to log the events, spring-security is completely silent. Which might be a clue...

```
log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target = System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern = %-5p %d [%t][%F:%L] : %m%n
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

The only thing I can think of that's really different from my local setup is the fact that on the remote server nginx sits in front of jetty.

***Does somebody have a clue what might be going wrong here?***

Here are relevant parts of the configurations.

#### nginx

```
location /test-app {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/test-app;
}
```

---

#### web.xml (spring-security)

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

---

#### spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

        <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
                <authentication-provider>
                        <user-service>
                                <user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                        </user-service>
                </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>

        <http auto-config="true">
                <intercept-url pattern="/secured/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
                <intercept-url pattern="/secured/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

                <form-login login-page="/secured/login" login-processing-url="/secured/login/auth"
                        authentication-failure-url="/secured/login?error=BadCredentials"
                        username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
                        default-target-url="/secured" />

                <logout logout-url="/secured/logout" logout-success-url="/secured" />
        </http>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: what happens in the "login-processing-url="/secured/login/auth"?

Comment: @Hippoom It is caught somewhere by the filter chain defined in web.xml. It's handled by spring-security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it working if you connect to remote jetty directly using port 8080?

If it is, the problem is probably related to nginx.

When Spring Security auth succeeds, it should be able to set a cookie on browser via Set-Cookie header in the response. Maybe nginx has trouble with that.

You could debug using the traffic with Chrome, press F12 and open Network tab. Go to login page and try to login. You should be able to see cookie JSESSIONID in the Cookies tab if it succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will check when I get the chance. I always have the developer tools opened in chrome while debugging and I saw the cookie being set. What worries me as well is that I couldn't find any log entries concerning spring security with the configuration in my question.

Comment: Connecting directly to jetty makes everything work so it certainly is nginx spoiling all the fun.

Comment: I found the culprit! After changing parts of my *sites-available/default* config I found my changes did not have any effect whatsoever. I looked inside the *sites-enabled* folder and found a file called *default* as well with some old settings. I replaced that file with a symbolic link to the correct config and everything is fine now. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

My problem is the same. As I recognized, my application makes a redirect when the URL does not contain the trailing slash.

For example:
http://example.com/myapp --> http://example.com/myapp/ redirection.

And when you activate spring security and start with the first url, then redirects to http://example.com/login, after a successful authentication this goes back to the http://example.com/myapp, and a new cycle begins.

Try your app with the slash at the end of the URL, or examine how to solve this problem when users types the URL without the trailing slash.